# SMTP Server setting on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, smtp, telnet

I am very very new to this and just trying to configure SMTP virtual server. I have followed a few threads to get it all running, but the mails are not being delivered.

What I have done so far -

1) Install SMTP server.

2) SMTP server *Properties*

- *General Tab* - IP address is set to '***All Unassigned***'.
- *Access Tab* - ***Authentication*** is anonymous access. Everything else is left to Default settings.
- *Delivery Tab* - ***Outbound security*** is anonymous access. In ***Advance*** section, entered the domain name in the FQDN field, and **localhost** in ***Smart host*** field.

3) Created an Inbound Rule for SMTP service to allow connections to Port **25**.

When I try to telnet, everything works up until the point the mail has to be send. Now, the sender's domain is different to the receiver's domain. 
Not sure if settings have to be changed to allow that?

I had set the **Relay restrictions** on SMTP server, but because I couldn't send the mails, I thought I might as well make it work without the relay first.

The error I see while sending the mail is `451 Timeout waiting for client input`.
I used to get some other error before when I had Relay restrictions on.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May need to add outbound rule for port 25. Also try removing smarthost from advanced tab

Based on comments for restrictions:

SMTP Virtual Server Properties:
Access tab -> Connections  > Add IP of server connecting to send mail.

For example if your  web server is sending mail then add its IP address. IF you want anyone on your network to be able to connect then add you entire subnet. (192.168.0.0 - 255.255.255.0) < that will all IP address between 192.168.0.1/254) to connect.

Do the same for Access tab -> Relay.

Comment: Great! That worked. Thanks so much! Hopefully it would work with the relay restrictions back on.

Comment: Doesn't work if I put back the relay restrictions? Do I need them?

Comment: Depends what the server is being used for.  if its just an internal SMTP server for outgoing only then I would put restrictions on it. needs both relay and connection restrictions.

Comment: If you're having issues with restrictions updated the question with the use and restrictions set.

Comment: Yes, Tyron. It is only for outgoing mail. I don't have any restrictions set at the moment.

Comment: @user223298 updated answer